# Get all the rows raleted with a specific string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am using rails with a postgresql db, and I would like to know which is the best solution, in getting all the rows which are similar with a string.

string format: `domain.com` or `domain.com/uk` or `subdomain.domain.com`

db column format : `http://www.test.com/All-test/test1/test2-test3/`

So I would like to get from my table all the rows which are matching with my string.
Currently I have a script which is going through all the rows in my table, and taking the column values, from where it takes the host and compares it with the string.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the [LIKE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html) function is what you want to use. You can use in in an ActiceRecord query like this:

```
search_string = "domain.com"
YourModel.where("db_column LIKE ?", "%#{search_string}%").first
```

You might need to refine the search, but the link above should give you all the tools you need